Decay of the impulse response for poles contained in the unit circle
I've been struggling with the following exercise in Ljung's "System Identification: Theory for the User" (Problem 3G.1):
Given a rational transfer function $G(z)$ such that its poles are all contained in $|z| \leq \mu$ where $\mu < 1$, show that
$$ |g(k)| \leq c \cdot \mu^k. $$
Here, $g(k)$ is defined by
$$ G(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty g(k) z^{-k}. $$
Since the poles are all contained in the unit circle, the inverse of the z-transform should just be the inverse Fourier transform, but I don't quite see how to bound that either. I've read in several places that the impulse response decays whenever the poles are contained in the unit circle, but I haven't been able to find a proof. Any help would be appreciated.

The transfer function $G(z)$ is usually expressed as a ratio of $\mathcal{z}$-transforms in the following way:
$$G(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{b_0 + b_1z^{-1} + b_2z^{-2} +\,\cdots + b_Mz^{-M}}{1+ a_1z^{-1} + a_2z^{-2} +\,\cdots + a_Nz^{-N}}$$
If $G(z)$ is strictly proper ($M < N$), it can also be expressed using partial fraction decomposition/expansion:
$$G(z) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{r_i}{1-p_iz^{-1}}$$
where $r_i$ are the residues of the poles $p_i$. Notice that each term in that sum is a first order system.

For $M \geq N$, other steps are needed but we'll leave that out here, see the end of this answer

The inverse $\mathcal{z}$-transform of each of these terms is a geometric series:
$$\mathcal{Z}^{-1}\bigg\{\frac{r_i}{1-p_iz^{-1}}\bigg\} = r_ip_i^k$$
So the inverse $\mathcal{z}$-transform of $G(z)$ yields:
$$g(k) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}r_ip_i^k$$

$k = 0,1,2,\cdots$

Given that the poles $p_i$ are bounded by $\mu < 1$, i.e. $|p_i| < \mu$, each term $|p_i|^k$ is also bounded $|p_i^k| < \mu^k$. Can you take it from there? Try yourself before clicking on the spoiler.

 Therefore, the magnitude of each component of the impulse response decays exponentially with $k$, and we can write: $$|g(k)| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N}|r_i||p_i^k| \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}|r_i|\right)\mu^k$$ Setting $c = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}|r_i|\right)$, which is a finite constant since $N$ is finite, concludes the proof.

For more details, I suggest you read through this chapter from INTRODUCTION TO DIGITAL FILTERS by Julius O. Smith III

Thanks for the detailed answer! One quick question, are the residues automatically bounded?

for stable systems (poles inside the unit circle), yes.

Ok. I don't quite see immediately why this is the case... is there a simple explanation?

Yes! start with the expression for residues: $$r_i = \lim_{z\to p_i}G(z)$$ do you see why necessarily $r_i$ is bounded if $|p_i| < 1$?

Ah so since the stability guarantees that the transfer function is bounded for bounded input we get that the limit is always bounded as well?

I mis-typed:
$$r_i = \lim_{z\to p_i}(z-p_i)G(z)$$
yes to your previous comment
